# How to skip a before filter custom class in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I have a Ruby on Rails Controller with a `before_filter` using a custom class:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter CustomBeforeFilter      
end
```

I have another controller inherited from `ApplicationController`, where I would like to skip the `CustomBeforeFilter`:

```
class AnotherController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter CustomBeforeFilter
end
```

That doesn't work. The `before_filter` is still executed.

How can I skip a Ruby on Rails before filter that uses a custom class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class callbacks are assigned a random callback name when they are added to the filter chain. The only way I can think of to do this is to find the name of callback first:

```
skip_before_filter _process_action_callbacks.detect {|c| c.raw_filter == CustomBeforeFilter }.filter
```

If you want something a little cleaner in your controllers, you could override the skip_before_filter method in ApplicationController and make it available to all controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def self.skip_before_filter(*names, &block)
    names = names.map { |name|
      if name.class == Class
        _process_action_callbacks.detect {|callback| callback.raw_filter == name }.filter
      else
        name
      end
    }

    super
  end
end
```

Then you could do:

```
class AnotherController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter CustomBeforeFilter
end
```

Answer (score 2):

you could just wrap your custom class in a method like so:

```
before_filter :custom
def custom
  CustomBeforeFilter.filter(self)
end
```

and then disable that filter wherever you want

Comment: The cleanest solution came from Beerlington, but I opted for your solution at the end, because my real scenario also has to delay the execution of the filter and pass an optional variable to the `CustomBeforeFilter.filter` method.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be to return from your before_filter method if the current controller is the one you want to skip:

```
class CustomBeforeFilter
  def self.filter(controller)
    return if params[:controller] == "another"
    # continue filtering logic
  end
end
```

EDIT:

Following phoet advice you can also use `controller.controller_name` instead of `params[:controller]`

Comment: dude, you get yielded the controller, but you are asking the params?

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I opted for another one, because the `CustomBeforeFilter` class should not be aware of the controller it is called in.